# Trying to upgrade to 17.10 from 17.04

Tags: upgrade, 17.10

When attempting to upgrade to 17.10 from 17.04 I recieve the following error:

```
W:GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E:The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric InRelease' is not signed.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: How *exactly* did you try to perform the release upgrade? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` and the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? Thanks.

Comment: "oneiric"? That's Ubuntu 11.10!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)